# How to buy a laptop with Ubuntu pre-installed

Tags: lenovo, preinstallation

I would like to know how to buy a laptop with ubuntu preinstalled to ensure the hardware compatibility at 100%. I like very much the Thinkpad T Series or the X1-carbon but I'm open to other alternatives.

Thanks

Comment: System76, ZAReason, Dell "Dev edition", etc. What's stopping you?

Comment: "how"? you go to a store or website where they sell computers. All you need to take care of: make sure the NIC is supported. All other hardware tends to work nowadays.

Comment: Puri.sm, slimbook.es to add some good other choices

Comment: learning to install linux is an essential skill which will repay you in spades later on ... if it helps, just practice doing a few ubuntu installs on a toy laptop ... also have access to a 2nd working computer while you battle any install questions, as they are all solvable today unlike attempting to install linux many years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu is compatible with most of the laptops out there. Beware that some with AMD CPUs / GPUs might require extra work or not perform as well since they don't seem to be part of the Linux Consortium like Intel or even nVidia. This is an impression not the Gospel Truth.

You can buy laptops with Ubuntu pre-installed if you think that is wise:

[image: laptops with ubuntu preinstalled.png]

Google (search engine anyways) is your friend.

Comment: I find that AMD  CPU/GPU machines are just as stable as Nvidia or Intel

Comment: @ScottStensland As I said it's not the gospel truth. Thank you for your input.